# ES6 script errors out after processed through webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a script that is written in ES6. When I use it in a modern browser, it works fine. Everything is great. Then I pass it through webpack so that it can run on older browsers. However the output code then drops the following in my console window.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined
    at Register.componentDidUpdate (Register.jsx:8)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:729
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (CallbackQueue.js:76)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (ReactReconcileTransaction.js:80)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:206)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:153)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:140)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at Object.flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
```

If you are curious abaout what is in Register.jsx on line 8:

```
parent.globalBroadcaster.dispatch('react_app.Register.componentDidUpdate', true);
```

Like I said, the code works fine in modern browsers before I run it through webpack, so I am assuming there is something with my webpack.config.js that is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: {
    ReactApp: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.jsx'],
    GlobalBroadcaster: './src/GlobalBroadcaster.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../public'),
    publicPath: '/react',
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.scss', '.css', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modulesDirectories: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: { presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'] },
      }, {
        test: /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]!postcss!sass'),
      },
    ],
  },
  postcss: [autoprefixer],
  sassLoader: {
    data: '@import "styles/_variables.scss";',
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src')],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/reactApp.css', { allChunks: true }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Promise: 'es6-promise',
      fetch: 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
    }),
  ],
};
```

GlobalBroadcaster.js

```html
/**
* Very basic means of dispatching messages from event generators to interested subscribers
*/
class GlobalBroadcaster {
  constructor() {
    this.events = {};
  }
  /**
   * Called by event generators to inform subscribers.
   *
   * @param string event: a string identifying the event name
   * @param mix data: message to communicate to subsribers
   */
  dispatch(event, data) {
    if (!this.events[event]) return; // no subscribers
    this.events[event].forEach(subscriber => subscriber(data));
  }
  /**
   * Means to subscribe a callback function to a given event.
   * @param string event: a string identifying the event name
   * @param function subscriber: a function to call back when the given event takes place
   */
  subscribe(event, subscriber) {
    if (!this.events[event]) this.events[event] = []; // new event
    this.events[event].push(subscriber);
  }
}

var globalBroadcaster = new GlobalBroadcaster();
```

Comment: The error is saying `parent.globalBroadcaster` is `undefined`, so we'll need to see the code that sets that. What is `parent` and where does it come from?

Comment: parent is part of javascript. Like parent.window. globalBroadcaster is the var I have created and loaded separately on its own via the GlobalBroadcaster.js file I have pasted above. So I just access the globalBoradcaster with parent.globalBroadcaster. Also, parent.globalBroadcaster is working fine before I process the GlobalBroadcaster.js file through webpack.

Comment: Ah okay. If you were loading it without Webpack before, you were creating a global variable. Webpack wraps every file in a module wrapper, so all of your variables are scoped per-file, so if you want to create a global you'd have to do it explicitly.

Comment: ah, thank you. Now that I know the problem, I can work on trying to make it a global again. Just got to figure how to do that with webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone curious, I just had to edit my last line of the GlobalBroadcaster file from:

```
var globalBroadcaster = new GlobalBroadcaster();
```

to

```
window.globalBroadcaster = new GlobalBroadcaster();
```

As stated in the comments, webpack puts the output code inside a scope. If you want to access it globally, like I was, you have to attach the function to the window.

Comment: Alternatively, configure webpack to export your exports into the global scope.